# Convert composer json to .php file

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I downloaded a script that it's with composer json. How can I convert it to normal php files and use it on shared host. My shared host doesn't support composer scripts.

Comment: and why you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `composer.json` file only contains the instructions to download the appropriate libraries. The actual code is inside the `vendor` subdirectory. You don't need to do anything at all with that file in your hosting service. Just upload the code, it should work as-is (as long as it doesn't have additional issues unrelated to Composer).

Answer (score 0):

Well,
You can use this code to convert whole .json file into an array..

So, first step is to read `.json` file and then converting it into an array using `json_decode()` function because `.json` file contains json string.

```
<?php
$read_file = file_get_contents('composer.json');

print_r(json_decode($read_file, true));
?>
```